# Flex Box - White Space in IE 11

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a project with flex box and currently I am struggling with the view from Internet Explorer 11.

In Chrome, Edge, Firefox everything looks good - after the container the browser window is ending. 
But in Internet Explorer 11 I get a white empty space at the bottom. 
I have checked lots of different solutions, but nothing is working. 
Do you have a hint for me.

Thanks a lot.

I have implemented a flex-container:

```css
.flex-container {
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And in the flex-container I have two flex elements with these settings:

```css
.flex-container-one {
    width: 70%;
    text-align: left;
}

.flex-container-two {
    width: 30%;
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Please also add your HTML so we can see what the DOM looks like. Also, is it so bad? Nobody should optimise for IE11 anymore. If it works and it isn't perfect, that should be acceptable now.

Comment: Please also add the necessary HTML so we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: I also have the same issue. The below mentioned amswer seems to be not working.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that there is some padding-bottom value that explorer is using by default for the .flex-container. Also since you didn't specify the height it is being set by the height of the content within and their default values. Specifying the height can solve your issue.